# How to debug a Ohai plugin?

Tags: debugging, plugins, chef-infra

What is the best way to debug an Ohai plugin on chef. 'ohai' command gets the data for all the plugins. Is there a command to debug a single Ohai plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run just your plugin via `ohai $pluginname` on the command line. You can also use `-l debug` to turn up the logging level. From inside your code, use `Ohai::Log.debug('your message')`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the log output while running under Test Kitchen?